# If I create a HashMap which contains only lowercase letter as key(max 26), what is the space complexity

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, hashset

Also for the Hashset has only lowerletter case.

Is this O(1)/ or O(N)

Not the performance.

Eg: A leetcode problem
Map<Character,Integer>store = new HashMap<>();
store only contains lowercase letter as key.
Ask the space Complexity, is this O(1)/O(N).

Comment: I mean, technically, all real computing is O(1) because there's a maximum amount of memory space in the universe.  Do you think that's a useful way of thinking about it?

Comment: There *isn't* an answer to this question.  Technically, it's both depending on how you look at it.  It's up to you what N means in your program when it's bounded.

Comment: @LouisWasserman is the distinction you are trying to make that, since N is a constant (26), we can view the space requirement as constant *for this use.* For example, I'm using this map to convert characters in a string from lower to upper case. The space required might depend on the string length, but its constant with respect to the conversion table. Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

On average, hashed collections (maps or sets) require O(n) space and O(1) time for insert, search, and delete operations. You can think of a hash map as a hash set with some extra information linked to the key.

In your case, if `n` is the constant 26, O(26) ≈ O(1). Constant space is required for this aspect of the algorithm that depends on this mapping.